# Difference between two statistical approaches to the same question

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you have some True/False question that you survey 50 people about. 30 people answer correctly. Consider each response as a Bernoulli trial. Do you reject the null hypothesis that $p=0.5$?

---

Approach 1: Find the sampling distribution of $p_{hat}$ and check whether $p$ is in the 95% confidence interval of that sampling distribution:

$E(p_{hat}) = 30/50 = 0.6$, and $\sigma(p_{hat}) = \sqrt(\frac{p_{hat}*(1-p_{hat})}{50}) = 0.07$

```
> qnorm(0.025,.6,0.06928203)
[1] 0.4642097
> qnorm(0.975,.6,0.06928203)
[1] 0.7357903
```

Since $p$ is in $(0.46,0.73)$, fail to reject the null.

---

Approach 2:

Take $p = 0.5$ as a given, and find the probability of observing 30 or more successes. If this is less than 0.05, reject the null:

```
> 1-pbinom(29,50,.5)
[1] 0.101
```

Since this is not less than 0.05, do not reject the null.

---

Are these two approaches identical, such that one approach fails to reject the null if and only if the other one does?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a computational mistake toward the top:

$$E(p_{\text{hat}}) = 30/50 = \color{red}{0.6}$$

---

Edit to address your corrected / amended question: they will overwhelmingly agree, though you may find very rare corner cases where they appear not to. One reason for this is that the top approach uses a continuous distribution to approximate the probabilities, and the bottom approach does not. These differences will be very minor and will almost never occur in practice.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Note also that to compute the $95\%$ CI, you should use $0.025$ and $0.975$ as the first parameter of ```qnorm``` so that you carve out the inner $95\%$ of the area.

Comment: Also, your $p$-value should be two-sided if you want it to correspond to a two-sided CI, so you should double it.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment - can you please elaborate about doubling the p-value?

Comment: See this for an overview of what I'm talking about: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/ A $95\%$ CI naturally corresponds to a two-tailed $p$-value, because the CI corresponds to the light blue (i.e. not the dark blue) regions on the normal curves on that link. The way to take a one-tailed $p$-value such as you have computed, and turn it into a two-tailed $p$-value, is to double it (unless it already exceeds $0.5$).